# what must be hashcode of null objects in Java?

Tags: java, object, hashmap, hashcode

According to a comment from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184041/how-is-hashcode-calculated-for-null-object), `hascode` of `null objects` can `throw NPE` or a value of `zero`. This is implementation specific. but within the same implementation, why does 
`Objects.hashcode` and `hascode(instance)` return different values. for ex:

```
public class EqualsTesting {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String p1 =null;
        String p2 = null;
        System.out.println(Objects.hashCode(p1));
        System.out.println(p2.hashCode());

    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BinaryTrees.EqualsTesting.main(EqualsTesting.java:14)
```

If this is the case, will this not affect the `key look-up` in `HashMap` where `null Key-value pairs` are allowed. (It might either `hash` to `bucket 0` or `throw a NPE`)

Comment: Cause 1st one is static method and second one is non-static

Comment: @tintinmj: so why should they return different values?

Comment: You can't call `hashCode()` or any other method on `null`.

Comment: You can't call any instance method of a `null` reference. This is not specific to the `hashCode()` method.

Comment: *"According to a comment from this post ..."* - I advise you not try to read too much in to a one-line comment.  Read the real Answers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How would you calculate `hashCode` of an object that doesn't even exists? When `p2` is `null`, invoking any method on it will throw a `NPE`. That isn't giving you any particular value of a hashCode.

`Objects.hashCode()` is just a wrapper method, which performs a pre-check for `null` values, and for reference that is not `null`, it returns the same value as `p2.hashCode()` as in this case. Here's the source code of the method:

```
public static int hashCode(Object o) {
    return o != null ? o.hashCode() : 0;
}
```

Comment: so does HashMap uses Objects.hasCode() to calculate the hash for null?

Comment: @eagertoLearn: No, take a look at my answer, there is special handling for that.

Comment: @eagertoLearn No it doesn't. It just uses the value `0` for `null` key.

Comment: so where exactly are these static Objects.hashCode() useful?

Comment: @eagertoLearn: If you don't want to bother with explicitly checking for `null` before getting `hashCode`.

Comment: @eagertoLearn You can use it anywhere you are calculating the `hashCode` of an object. It just saves you extra `nullity` check and avoids possible `NPE`.

Comment: @eagertoLearn You can always look at the source code of any data structure if you want to know how it is implemented. Source code is distributed with jdk that you have installed.

Comment: HashMap was written before the `Objects` helper class was. If `Objects` had been around, `HashMap` may have used it.

Answer (score 6):

If you will search around, you'll notice that `HashMap` has a [special handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268212/hashcode-for-null-key-in-hashmap) for `null` keys. `null` values are fine as you don't compute hash code for them in a `HashMap`. This is the reason why `null` keys work fine in `HashMap`. As to why `Objects.hashCode` works fine, take a look at Rohit's answer.

Comment: Also @sanjay null check is done in hashmap put() method. if it is null then a separate method is invoked from put.

Answer (score 3):

As [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) says:

> Objects.hashCode(Object o)
>
> Returns the hash code of a non-null argument and 0 for a null
>   argument.

`p2.hashCode()` throws a `NullPointerException` because you are trying to access a method of a null object.

Answer (score 3):

> According to a comment from this post, hascode of null objects can throw NPE or a value of zero.

That is not true.  (And it is not what @Bohemian's comment is saying!)

What happens in `HashMap` and `HashSet` is that they treat `null` as a special case.  Instead of calling `hashcode()` on the `null` object (which would NPE!!), they use zero in as a hard-coded alternative hashcode.

I stress ... this is special case behaviour of `HashMap` and `HashSet` ... not `hashcode()`.

As your example shows, if you *do* attempt to call the `hashcode()` method on `null`, you *will* get an NPE.  The JLS says that that is what will happen ... and it happens whenever you try to invoke *any* instance method on `null`.

(On the other hand, the `Objects.hashCode(obj)` method *does* deal with the case where `obj` is `null` as a special case.  And that's the whole point of the static method!)

Comment: then why is it implementation specific as commented by Bohemian?

Comment: It is specific to the implementation of whatever you are implementing how you handle this issue.  In the `HashMap` / `HashSet` case, it is also implementation specific what *value* is used as the *ersatz* hash value for `null` objects.  However, in order to satisfy the javadoc, an implementation of `HashMap` or `HashSet` cannot allow a (hypothetical) NPE to reach user code in the `null` case.

Answer (score 0):

The hash code of `null` is 0 (see `Objects.hash()`)

```
    public static int hashCode(Object a[]) {
        if (a == null)
            return 0;

        int result = 1;

        for (Object element : a)
            result = 31 * result + (element == null ? 0 : element.hashCode());

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

0 is hard coded value for ***null*** in Hashmap. You can see the following actual implementations done in HashMap and Objects java classes.

from ***HashMap.java***

```
static final int hash(Object key) {
        int h;
        return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
    }
```

from ***Object.java***

```
public static int hashCode(Object o) {
        return o != null ? o.hashCode() : 0;
    }
```